# Appication error whlie using @Refreshscope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-config-server

I am having a Config server and Config Client,
I have injected property file value to my java class as shown below,

```
@RefreshScope
@Component
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
@Getter
public class PropConig{
      @Value("${welcome.message}") 
      private String message;
}
```

Property file has containing below code

`welcome.message = "Welcome to my app"`

And I have a JMS configuration class @**AutoWired** with **PropConig** as below where I used above property value

```
@EnableJms
@Log4j2
public class JmsConfig{
    @AutoWired PropConig propConig;
     
    -Here I am accessing the values using **propConig.message** 

}
```

Everything working fine but when  I am using @RefreshScope in PropConig.class it trowing error while starting the application.
Kindly help me.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: beans mentioned in JmsConfig class throwing  error as 'Unable o create bean...nested exception is...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use configuration properties and remove @value,@refreshScope

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample")
public class ConfigProperties {
    
    private String hostName;
    private int port;
    private String from;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

value of hostName is value of sample.hostName or sample.host-name in your application.properties

reference doc: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot